# Validating Google ID tokens in C#

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, google-plus

I need to validate a Google ID token passed from a mobile device at my ASP.NET web api.

Google have some sample code [here](https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-verifytoken-csharp) but it relies on a JWT NuGet package which is .Net 4.5 only (I am using C#/.Net 4.0). Is anyone aware of any samples which do this without these packages or has achieved this themselves? The use of the package makes it very difficult to work out what I need to do without it.

Comment: found anything? I also want to do it offline using C# because sometimes Google's server respond very slow.

Answer (score 27):

According to this github [issue](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/920#issuecomment-364922308), you can now use [`GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidateAsync`](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/Src/Support/Google.Apis.Auth/GoogleJsonWebSignature.cs#L70) method to validate a Google-signed JWT. Simply pass the `idToken` string to the method.

```
var validPayload = await GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidateAsync(idToken);
Assert.NotNull(validPayload);
```

If it is not a valid one, it will return `null`.

Note that to use this method, you need to install [Google.Apis.Auth](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Auth/) nuget firsthand.

Comment: Do you know how to decode it, so I can get the user id?

Comment: The GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidateAsync method returns a Payload object with the details of the token - e.g. it can include properties like Email, FamilyName, GivenName

Comment: As of Sept 2022 or earlier, ValidateAsync "Will throw a InvalidJwtException if the specified JWT fails any validation check." per Google https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Apis/latest/Google.Apis.Auth.GoogleJsonWebSignature So Assert.NotNull will never fail in your code.

Answer (score 2):

ClientId also needs to be passed, which should be set from Google API Console. If only pass TokenId, GoogleJsonWebSignature throws error. This answer is in addition to @edmundpie answer

```
var settings = new GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidationSettings()
{
 Audience = new List<string>() { "[Placeholder for Client Id].apps.googleusercontent.com" }
};

var validPayload = await GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidateAsync(model.ExternalTokenId, settings);
```

Answer (score 1):

The challenge is validating the JWT certificate in the ID token. There is currently not a library I'm aware of that can do this that doesn't require .Net 4.5 and until there is a solution for JWT validation in .NET 4.0, there will not be an easy solution.

However, if you have an access token, you can look into performing validation using [oauth2.tokeninfo](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/oauth2.tokeninfo/m/oauth2/v1/oauth2.tokeninfo). To perform basic validation using token info, you can do something like the following:

```
// Use Tokeninfo to validate the user and the client.
var tokeninfo_request = new Oauth2Service().Tokeninfo();
tokeninfo_request.Access_token = _authState.AccessToken;
var tokeninfo = tokeninfo_request.Fetch();
if (userid == tokeninfo.User_id
    && tokeninfo.Issued_to == CLIENT_ID)
{
    // Basic validation succeeded
}
else
{
    // The credentials did not match.
}
```

The information returned from the Google OAuth2 API tells you more information about a particular token such as the client id it was issued too as well as its expiration time.

**Note** You should not be passing around the access token but instead should be doing this check after exchanging a one-time code to retrieve an access token.

Comment: I don't actually pass the access token, just the id token. I only need to authenticate the user, not call any Google apis. I thought it was bad practice to pass access tokens around, is there a way to do this with just the id token? Thanks

Comment: I'll keep looking for a way for doing this without using .NET 4.5, it would be ideal to have a solution that works from 4.0 and up. Also, for validating the access token, what you would want to do is use the one-time code and exchange it for the access token as opposed to passing the access tokens around.