# Validating Google OAuth id token received from oauth2/v4/token

Tags: c#, .net, google-oauth, google-authentication

We are currently using Google OpenId Connect to authenticate our users.

I'm successfully retrieving the `access token` and `id token` via the `token_endpoint` as described [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#exchangecode). Later on I validate the `id token` as described [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#validatinganidtoken). The `token_endpoint` will be received via the [discovery document](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#discovery) (as recommended by Google).

**Problem**

But since a few days there seems to be a new version of the discovery document, because the `token_endpoint` has changed from

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token
```

to

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token
```

The new endpoint returns a slightly longer `id token` which can no longer be validated with `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?id_token=xxx`. The request returns with the error

```
{
 "error": "invalid_token",
 "error_description": "Invalid Value"
}
```

If I hard code the `token_endpoint` to the old url (`https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token`) everything works fine like before.

**Question**

Since the old [OpenID 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenID2Migration) has been shut down a few days ago, I thought there may be some correlation between the shutdown, the new `token_endpoint` and the validation of the `id_token`, but I couldn't find anything yet.

Is there any solution to validate the new slightly longer `id token` via the `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?id_token=xxx` url? For debugging it is easier to use the `tokeninfo` endpoint, later on in production we'll probably validate the token locally ([Validating Google ID tokens in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17114201/validating-google-id-tokens-in-c-sharp)).

Comment: You're right, there was a [new version](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29830503/72176) of the discovery document published last week. It looks like there is a bug in `tokeninfo` (which is not actually part of OpenID Connect, but I agree is a useful tool during development).  As a temporary workaround, you could go back to the old discovery document (and thus get the previous format id tokens), or avoid using `tokeninfo` and implement your local ID Token validation now.  This is a handy online tool for [inspecting JWTs](https://py-jwt-decoder.appspot.com/) during development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `invalid_token` error was caused by an issue in `v1/tokeninfo`, related to the [modified ID tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29830503/72176) from the `v4/token` endpoint, as you suspected. That issue has been resolved, and tokens should validate correctly again at `tokeninfo`. Thanks for your detailed post!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes it seems to work again. But because I had some time on my hands yesterday I implemented the local validation (as you suggested). The implementation is based on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29779351/333404. For debugging it is nice that `tokeninfo`works again.

Comment: Awesome! Local validation is definitely preferred when you go to production, so your time was well spent :)